# Sphinx + xmlpipes2 + Mysql Connector. Problems with cyrillic

Tags: c#, mysql, sphinx

I have a problem configuring sphinx+mysql on my machine (Windows 7).
I use sphinx 2.0.6 and MySQL connector 6.5.5 to get to sphinx from C# code. Everything works fine when I try to search a words in English ("madrid" for ex.). But when I send a query from C# code which contains a cyrillic word (that had to be indexed) I receive no results. Here is what I see in the "query.log" file:
[Tue Mar 26 16:35:12.642 2013] 0.000 sec [ext2/0/ext 0 (0,10)] [airportIndex] *????*

Latin words looks normal:

```
[Tue Mar 26 16:35:06.195 2013] 0.000 sec [ext2/0/ext 0 (0,10)] [airportIndex] *mosc*
```

The charset_table seems to be correct in config:

```
charset_type            = utf-8
charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, \
U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+0401->U+0435, U+0451->U+0435
```

I just don't know what to do. I've googled for solution the whole day I tried many different solutions, but none of them helped me. Maybe anyone could help me here? Please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It was a connector bug (or feature, I'm not sure). It was trying to get the server datetime offset, and failed because sphinx does not have this function. I've just commented this code line (inside MySql.Data.dll) and it started working correctly.